# using .slideDown to toggle a div on or off, also adjusting arrow

Tags: jquery, slidedown

Trying to create a div that is revealed below a link that slides to reveal when the ink is clicked.

I can't seem to get it working.

I also need to work out a way to make the ► change to a ▼ when the div is 'open', though this will probably need to be done with an image not an ascii character?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAjEK/2/)

Comment: Also as a side note, you had your jsfiddle set to use the MooTools library - This is found in the left-hand column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DAjEK/4/

Here's a completely different approach... Much more concise.

```
$("#colourList a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html($(this).is(':contains(▼)') ? 'See the colours ►' : 'Hide the colours ▼');
    $("#colours").slideToggle(500);
});​
```

Comment: +1 just added animate into your stuff for bit of non-flickeryness `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/7Hsv8/